# Adding hotspots with identical lat/long (dealing with large numbers of hotspots)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a database containing a large number of hotspots I want to display (~20,000, spread over one country). Obviously adding all of these at once causes immense strain on the device, so I'm trying to find alternative solutions.

I am currently using an onCameraChange listener to be notified when the user has moved the app, then only loading hotspots which are in the visible area of the screen. However, if the user only moves the map by a small amount, duplicate hotspots will be added. Is Google Maps clever enough to not add a duplicate hotspot?

To try and avoid this I was calling clear() on the map every time the user moved, and then loading the hotspots again. However, if the user clicks on a hotspot to view the associated title, then the map centers on it, causing the map to move and clearing then readding the hotspot, which instantly hides the title.

What would be the optimal solution of dealing with this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i would not "clear" and "readd" the markers but just hide them.
Instead of adding the points, just set it to visible if is inside the visible area, set it not visible otherwise
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setVisible(boolean)

I would suggest you to explore marker clusters in this library:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Comment: The problem I'm finding is if I add all of them upfront (as I would to make them visible/not visible) I have to add 20,000 in one go, which takes a long time and stops the UI from responding. I was hoping to reduce this by only adding the ones I need. I tried using clusters but faced the same problem (it took a long time to render them initially)

Comment: So you can adopt some sort of 'pagination' like adding and showing some and allow user to 'load more'? I dont think there is a way to show 20k point with zero lag...